# Can java get method with methodname through reflections

Tags: java

I know Java can get Method Object using the `Reflection.getMethod(...)` method，but the method needs method parameter types。 but I don't know the  exact parameter type。e.g.

```
byte a = 20;
System.out.println(a);
```

the `println` method hasn't the overload method `println(Byte)`，but has `println(Int)`。
How to get the println method through the byte type？
the other example

```
class MyClass
{
}
class MyClass1 extends MyClass
{
}
class TestClass
{
    public static void method1(MyClass c)
    {
        ... ...
    }
}
```

`TestClass.method1(new MyClass1())` is correct.but can i  get the `method1` through parameter type MyClass1 ?

`Class.getMethods` will get all method in Class， too much。 can i get all overload method same name？

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.Class` (see [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)) provides two ways of finding methods:

```
Method getMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)
```

and

```
Method[] getMethods()
```

(and corresponding `getDeclaredMethod()` variants).

So there's no API in the standard Java library for directly getting what you need - you'll need to get all methods, filter the ones with the right name, then inspect the parameter types.

Or you may be able to find a 3rd-party library that will do this for you. For example, the [reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library has a `getMethodsMatchParams(Class<?>... types)` method.

The [jOOR library](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOR) also provides various methods for finding methods with "similar" signatures.